# Error al escribir un algoritmo en LATEX

Tags: latex

Estoy trabajando con un plantilla para mi trabajo de grado, pero por mas que intento poner algoritmos en mi trabajo no lo logro siempre me da error

he intentado varios, como

```
\usepackage{algpseudocode} para  \begin{algorithmic}

\usepackage{verbatim}  para \begin{verbatim}

\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}

\begin{program}
```

pero siempre me generan un error, no puedo cambiar la plantilla asi que decidi poner imágenes y no se ve muy profesional, podrían ayudarme con esto?

La plantilla es la siguiente. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tdGrk2ppEM5jplYeZYl0w_m9x7VtcSEa/view?usp=sharing

Podrían ayudarme a revisar que es lo que esta fallando por favor??

Comment: Te sugiero que coloques un ejemplo mínimo que sea funcional de lo que quieres lograr y el texto completo del error, así será más sencillo ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: Para el trabajo de tesis recomiendo usar el template de [**TeXiS**](http://gaia.fdi.ucm.es/research/texis/) esta bien estructurado y es fácil agregar el tema de los códigos. Aca el ejemplo en [PDF](http://gaia.fdi.ucm.es/files/research/texis/nightlybuilds/TeXiS-Manual-NightlyBuild.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

Dices que te da error, pero no mencionas cuál. En todo caso, te aclaro algunas cosas y te pongo un ejemplo que he verificado que funciona con tu plantilla.

La forma más simple de escribir un pseudocódigo es simplemente ponerlo verbatim. Eso te da libertad a la hora de decidir qué escribir dentro. Puedes inventar tu propio "lenguaje de pseudocódigo", ya que lo que escribas ahí no será interpretado por latex de ninguna forma, y simplemente lo mostrará "tal cual".

Por ejemplo, un pseudocódigo para el algoritmo de Euclides sería:

```
\begin{verbatim}
procedure Euclides(a, b)      // Encuentra el máximo común divisor entre a y b
    r = a mod b
    while r != 0 do           // Si r es cero ya tendríamos la respuesta
        a = b
        b = r
        r = a mod b
    end while
    return b                   // El MCD es b
end procedure
\end{verbatim}
```

El lenguaje de pseudocódigo usado aquí es uno que marca los procedimientos como "procedures", el final de los bloques con un `end`, los comentarios con `//`, etc. Igualmente podría haber usado un estilo "python", en el que no se marque el final de los bloques sino que la indentación deje claro dónde acaban, etc.

Este entorno `verbatim` mostrará en tipo de letra de ancho fijo (tipo courier) el listado, sin aplicar ningún estilo especial a los comentarios, palabras reservadas, etc. El resultado tendría este aspecto:

> [image: Verbatim]

un problema que tiene es que el trozo verbatim no puede romperse entre páginas, por lo que mejor que no sea muy largo. Tampoco puedes referirte a él como lo harías a una figura o tabla.

Para resolver estos problemas puedes usar el paquete `algorithm`, que en realidad no sirve para escribir pseudocódigo, sino para crear un entorno llamado `algorithm` que se comporte como un "flotante", igual que una figura o tabla, al que le puedes poner `\caption{}` que va auto-numerando los algoritmos y al que puedes ponerle  `\label{}` para referirte a él. Incluso puedes crear un "Listado de algoritmos" en la tabla de contenidos. Dentro del entorno `algorithm` usarías otro entorno, como por ejemplo `verbatim` para crear el pseudocódigo en sí.

Se usaría por ejemplo así:

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Algoritmo de Euclides}
    \label{euclides}
\begin{verbatim}
  y aqui lo que quieras...
\end{verbatim}
\end{algorithm}
```

### Algorithmicx y algpseudocode

El entorno verbatim puede ser suficiente, pero uno de sus mayores problemas es que no permite usar matemáticas en su interior. Si quieres por ejemplo usar fórmulas en el pseudocódigo o en los comentarios, y pones algo entre `$`, ya que el verbatim no se interpreta, en el resultado aparecerían los `$` tal cual.

Otro paquete para hacer pseudocódigo que le da un formato más agradable y que permite usar matemáticas, es `algorithmicx`. El paquete `algpseudocode` es un envoltorio alrededor de `algorithmicx` que define una serie de comandos y estilos concretos. Basta `\usepackage{algpseudocode}`, pues éste se ocupa de incluir al otro.

El pseudocódigo que escribas ahora, en vez de en un `verbatim` irá en un entorno `algorithmic`, y lo que pongas dentro ya no es libre, sino que debes usar los comandos proporcionados por este paquete.

El ejemplo de Euclides sería ahora:

```
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclides}{$a,b$} \Comment{Encuentra el máximo común divisor entre $a$ y $b$}
        \State $r\gets a \bmod b$
        \While{$r\not=0$} \Comment{Si $r$ es cero ya tendríamos la respuesta}
            \State $a \gets b$
            \State $b \gets r$
            \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
        \EndWhile\label{euclidesfinwhile}
        \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{El M.C.D es $b$}
    \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
```

Y el aspecto con que aparecerá:

> [image: Algorithmicx]

Puedes ver que numera las líneas (y permite añadir una `\label{}` a cada una, por si quieres luego referirte a ellas. Permite también usar fórmulas, y las palabras especiales aparecen en negrita, y los comentarios alineados a la derecha y con un triangulito delante. Pero a cambio tienes que aprenderte todos los comandos necesarios para esto, y el código fuente del algoritmo queda más confuso.

Este entorno permite pseudocódigo largo, pues puede cortarlo si no cabe en la página. Si quieres que no lo corte, sino que lo mantenga junto en un flotante, puedes meter todo lo anterior dentro de un entorno `algorithm`, que le añadiría *caption*, numero de algoritmo, etc. Por ejemplo:

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Algoritmo de Euclides}
    \label{euclides}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    % Aqui iría lo de antes
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

El aspecto ahora sería el siguiente:

> [image: algorithm]

Para que todo lo anterior funcione, bastó añadir a tu `Tesis.tex` las tres líneas siguientes:

```
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{verbatim}
```